# Não estou conseguindo fazer o INNER JOIN no cakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, inner-join

Tudo bom pessoal?
Estou utilizando o cakePHP pra fazer um sistema que interaja com alguns dados do banco de dados de um site em Wordpress

no entanto toda vez que eu tento realizar uma consulta Inner Join o cake me mostra esse erro:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'WpPostmeta.meta_key' in 'where clause'

Meu codigo do Controller é esse:

```
$join = array(
        array(
            'table' => 'WpPostmeta',
            'alias' => 'wp-postmeta',
            'type' =>  'INNER',
            'conditions'=> array('WpPosts.ID = WpPostmeta.post_id',)
        )
    );
    $wpPosts  =  $this->RequestProduct->WpPosts->find('all',array(
        'joins' => $join,
        'conditions' => array('WpPostmeta.meta_key' => '_stock_status','WpPostmeta.meta_value' => 'instock') 
    )
    );
```

Porque o cake não está reconhecendo a coluna WpPostmeta se eu coloquei ele na variavel $join???

OBS: Olhei no debug e realmente o sql gerado pelo cake não esta me retornando essas colunas no select...

Esse é o meu código da classe WpPostmetaTable:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {

        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('wp_postmeta');
        $this->setDisplayField('meta_id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('meta_id');

        $this->belongsTo('WpPosts', [
            'foreignKey' => 'post_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }
```

E esse é o meu código da classe WpPostsTable:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {

        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('wp_posts');
        $this->setDisplayField('ID');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('ID');

        $this->hasMany('WpPostmeta', [
             'foreignKey' => 'post_id'
        ]);
    }
```

Esse é o Sql que eu queria que o cake fizesse:

```
    SELECT
     wp_posts.*,
     wp_postmeta.*
FROM
     `wp_posts` wp_posts INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.`ID` = wp_postmeta.`post_id`
WHERE
     wp_postmeta.`meta_key` = '_stock_status'
 AND wp_postmeta.`meta_value` = 'instock'
```

Também tentei dessa forma que é o que a documentação do cakePHP recomenda (mas da o mesmo erro...):

```
$wpPosts = $this->RequestProduct->WpPosts->find('all', [
        'contain' => [
            'WpPostmeta'
        ],
        'conditions' => [
            'WpPostmeta.meta_key' => '_stock_status',
            'WpPostmeta.meta_value' => 'instock'
        ]
]);
```

O cake não reconhece 'WpPostmeta.meta_key' e 'WpPostmeta.meta_value' como parte do Join...

Consegui resolver o meu problema com essa gambiarra:

```
$WpPostmetaTable = TableRegistry::get('WpPostmeta');
$WpPostmeta = $WpPostmetaTable->find('all', array(
   'conditions'=>array(
      'WpPostmeta.meta_key' => '_stock_status',
      'WpPostmeta.meta_value' => 'instock'
   )
));
$i = 0;
$wpPosts = array();
foreach ($WpPostmeta as $WpPostmetaArray){
    $wpPosts[$i] = $this->RequestProduct->WpPosts->get($WpPostmetaArray['post_id'], [
        'contain' => []
    ]);
    $WpPostmetaTemp = $WpPostmetaTable->find('all', array('conditions'=>array(
        'WpPostmeta.post_id' => $wpPosts[$i]['ID'])
    ));
    $wpPosts[$i]['wppostmeta'] = $WpPostmetaTemp;
    $i += 1;
}
```

Comment: não seria "wp_postmeta" ao invés de "wp-postmeta" ? Porque está definindo um alias, se não estar utilizando-o?

Comment: Mesmo que eu mude o nome e utilize o alias continua dando o mesmo erro... Error: Unknown column 'wp_postmeta.meta_key' in 'where clause'